# Distance between 2 3D points(GPS+altitude) in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gps, distance

I have 2 points, look like: (lat,lon,altitude in meters).
How can I get the distance between them?

I saw only `ST_3DDistance(geometry g1, geometry g2);`

But I don't know how to set points coordinates right way..
Because I have GPS + altitude also.

As suggested by Niklas

```
WITH geom_1 AS (
    SELECT ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(Lon, Lat), 4326),32637) 
    ), point_3d AS (
    SELECT  ST_MakePoint(ST_X(st_transform),ST_Y(st_transform), 0) FROM geom_1
    ), static_points AS (SELECT geom FROM eco.static_points WHERE name='Moscow')
SELECT ST_3DDistance(st_makepoint, geom) FROM point_3d, static_points;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ST_3DDistance you have to have all dimensions in the same unit, or the answer will not make sense. So use ST_Transform to project your GPS points to a suitable meter based (if altitudes are in meters) projection for the area of the points.

**edit**
In Moscow you can use UTM37, which is SRID 32637

So to transform your data use

```
ST_Transform(geom, 32637)
```

Then you have to make the altitude the z-value of the geometries.
Since you have points it is easy. You can do something like:

```
-- If you have a table like this:

the_table
(
    lat double precision,
    lon double precision,
    altitude double precision
);

-- First create a PostGIS geometry from lat, lon 
--(I might be wrong about lat, lon, or lon, lat order, I never do this)
CREATE TABLE table_a AS
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lat, lon), 4326) geom, altitude FROM the_table;

--Then transform (project) the data
CREATE TABLE table_b AS    
SELECT ST_Transform(geom) geom, altitude FROM table_a;

-- And create a table with 3D points
CREATE TABLE points_3d
SELECT ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom), altitude) geom FROM table_b
```

Now you have PostGIS 3D geometries that you can use with ST_3DDistance.

You can of course put the queries above in one single query.

Comment: I see, can you suggest which transformation can I use for getting cartesian coordinates from my set (lat, lon, alt). Thank you.

Comment: That depends on where in the world your points are.

Comment: My geolocation is Moscow city.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've tried to make single query but no success.. All I finally need is only distance. If you write a query I will appreciate it very much

Comment: I did it! Please give some comments if there is something to improve.